# Checking if an array element has a particular value

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Am trying to put together a method that looks through a Codeigniter shopping cart and determines the type of transaction based on the id of the items in the cart

Heres the method

```
function parse_transaction_type() {
            $card_skus = array("MYU_SC1","MYU_SC2","MYU_SC3");
            $fee_skus = array("MYU_SF1","MYU_AD1","MYU_AD2");
            foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $key => $item) {
                if(in_array($item['id'], $card_skus) && in_array($item['id'], $fee_skus))
                {
                    $type = "fees-cards";
                }
                if (in_array($item['id'], $card_skus) && !in_array($item['id'], $fee_skus))
                {
                    $type ="cards";
                }
                if (in_array($item['id'], $fee_skus) && !in_array($item['id'], $card_skus))
                {
                    $type ="fees";
                }
            }

            echo $type;
        }
```

The method only returns either "cards" or "fees" even when both are present. What am doing wrong?

Comment: The echo is outside the foreach loop so it is only showing the last `$type` that it sees.  Is that the issue?

Comment: @drew010 yeah that seems to be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use boolean flags for each type you are checking for, then assign the string (or do whatever) based on the value of the two flags. Initialize them to FALSE before your loop, then when you discover an item of each type, set it's flag to TRUE.

You can then optimize the loop to check if both are already true and `break`, so that in the case where the first two items are one of each, you can skip the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Your code passes the first `if` because the term is in both. The script continues to your second `if` where it passes again and reassigns `$type` You should use `else if` instead.

```
parse_transaction_type() {
  $card_skus = array("MYU_SC1","MYU_SC2","MYU_SC3");
  $fee_skus = array("MYU_SF1","MYU_AD1","MYU_AD2");
  foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $key => $item) {
    if(in_array($item['id'], $card_skus) && in_array($item['id'], $fee_skus)){
      $type = "fees-cards";
    }
    else if (in_array($item['id'], $card_skus) && !in_array($item['id'], $fee_skus)){
      $type ="cards";
    }
    else if (in_array($item['id'], $fee_skus) && !in_array($item['id'], $card_skus)){
      $type ="fees";
    }
  }
  echo $type;
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought it was at first, but after thinking about it, these conditions should never conflict with each other.